# module `require` base path

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm using Typescript. My sources are in `src`. When transpiling, Typescript outputs its results to the `lib` folder. Thus, when requiring my package components, I have to write the following:

```
import { myModuleMain } from 'mylib/lib'
import { ComponentA }   from 'mylib/lib/ComponentA'
import { ComponentB }   from 'mylib/lib/ComponentB'
```

Ok, when it happens just once, it's okay. The problem is when requiring several or many of those components. There are just dozen of `/lib` path segments everywhere, and I'm trying to get rid of it, to simply do the following:

```
import { myModuleMain } from 'mylib'
import { ComponentA }   from 'mylib/ComponentA'
import { ComponentB }   from 'mylib/ComponentB'
```

I should find a way to define my lib's base path. But as far as I saw, I had to change the `require`'s searching paths in my lib's code. Is there a way to achieve the same behaviour without changing this search path? Via a `package.json` property, for example?

I voluntarily omit the option to export all my components in a single `main` entry point, because files other than my `main` one are not supposed to be used by the final user: only plugins may use them. In other words, I'd like to have *multiple* entry points, all in the `lib` folder. Using the `main` property in `package.json` only simplifies the `import` statement for the 1st module, *eg* `myModuleMain`

Answer (score 0):

I use `main` on library config (package.json):

```
{
    "name": "mylib",
    "description": "My library...",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "./lib/index.js",
    ......
}
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main):

> The main field is a module ID that is the primary entry point to your
>   program. That is, if your package is named foo, and a user installs
>   it, and then does require("foo"), then your main module's exports
>   object will be returned.
>
> This should be a module ID relative to the root of your package
>   folder.
>
> For most modules, it makes the most sense to have a main script and
>   often not much else.

Also, on ts.config I have this configuration:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./lib",    
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But I'm looking for another solution: I've edited my question to better show my problem. Actually, having a single entry-point file is not really what I want: I'd like to have *multiple* entry points relative to my `lib` folder.

Answer (score 0):

> Thus, when requiring my package components, I have to write the following:

Well, you can just [import the files themselves.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) You don't have to require the transpiled version.

```
# foo.ts
export default function f (): void {
  console.log('foo')
}
```

Now you have `app.ts`

```
import f from './foo';
f();
```

You should totally ignore the transpiled outputs.